# What are my options for taking messages from an Azure Event Hub and an Azure Service Bus Topic and placing them into an Azure Storage Blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-servicebus-topics

We need to ingest messages from an Event Hub and Topic into a third party system. However, this system doesn't support Event Hubs and Topics yet, but it does support Blob storage. We'd like to temporarily drop these Event Hub and Topic messages into a Blob.

I thought I could use Data Factory for this, but it doesn't seem like it can connect to an Event Hub or Topic.

Using the Azure platform, what are my options for placing messages from an Event Hub and Topic into Blob storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is solution going to be hosted on Azure (can only assume) or on-premises?
What's the load on the system? I'm assuming if you are going with EventHubs then there's a substantial number of messages. Do you need to perform any processing aside from storing in Storage Blobs? Do you want to go with PaaS/Serverless/VMs?

Bottom line, there's no best way. Period.
There are scenarios and options you can choose from.
Without knowing specific details of your scenario, it's easy to point to *a solution* which is not necessarily a correct one.

You could try Azure Functions as a starting point. It offers both [EventHubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs) and [ServiceBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) incoming bindings and [Storage Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob) output binding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I worded my question poorly, I just wanted to know what my options were. I thought Data Factory could work, but it doesn't seem to have capability of hooking up to an Event Hub or Topic. We have a third party system that can currently only read from Blob, so we want to temporarily place these messages into Blob so that the third party system can access it. We are 100% on Azure. Max load is 1,000 messages per second. No processing is needed.

Comment: Then I'd give suggested Azure Functions a try. With such a load, you might consider a WebApp hosting plan rather than Consumption plan.